# Removing a json key/value pair from a json list in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I have data in a JSON (note: not `jsonb`) column that can look like any of the following:

```
[{"question": "Did you upload the file?"}]
or
[{"question": "Did you upload the file?"}, 'choice_1', 'Yes']
or
null
or
[]
or
etc...
```

I am attempting to remove all occurrences of the `question` key and its value from the list of values.

I've tried countless things to no avail including updating table `set column = column - 'question'`, using combinations of `jsonb` functions, and none seem to work.  I suspect it's because this list isn't simple values like `['a', 'b', 'c']`, and I just haven't found the right combination of approaches to work yet.

If the column contains the `{'question': 'some random question'}` key, I want the entire key/value pair removed from the list.

examples (Note:, only the first item below is actually changed):

```
[{'color': 'blue'}, {'question': 'what time is it'}] **->** [{'color': 'blue'}]

[{'something': 'something_else'}] **->** [{'something': 'something_else'}}

[] **->** []
```

Comment: 1. Are you really using version 9.5? That is a decade old. 2. What do you expect the output to look like with your example data? Please edit your question.

Comment: Updated @RichardHuxton.  We are using a modern/recent version of Postgres and updated for expected output/change.

Comment: You aren't removing a key/value pair there, you are removing an entire object. Do you want to remove any object containing key="something"?

Comment: Yes, remove any object in the list that has a key equal to 'question'.  Thank you @RichardHuxton.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest - if you've got this sort of fiddly nonsense going on you probably want to rethink your data schema. However, I think this does what you want:

```
WITH array_elements (e) AS (
    SELECT jsonb_array_elements(
        '["z", 1, {"question":"something", "foo":"bar"}, 3, {"other":"object"}]'::jsonb
    )
)
, filtered_elements AS (
    SELECT e FROM array_elements WHERE NOT e ? 'question'
)
SELECT jsonb_agg(e) FROM filtered_elements;

┌──────────────────────────────────┐
│            jsonb_agg             │
├──────────────────────────────────┤
│ ["z", 1, 3, {"other": "object"}] │
└──────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

I've done it as a series of CTEs (WITH clauses) to make it easier to understand.

We take our initial random selection of things in a JSON array and turn it into one row for each element.

Then we filter out any object with "question" as a top-level key.

Then we put them back into an array.

NOTE 1: I don't think we can *guarantee 100%* that the order of the array will be preserved. It almost certainly will be because there is nothing in the sequence to upset the order they come out of the initial JSON array.

NOTE 2: There may well be some way to do this with JSON Path queries, but I'm not familiar enough with that to try it.